# How to send mail automatically in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have used the following to display mailViewController

```
-(IBAction)sendMailbuttonTapped {

if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailCont = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailCont.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailCont setSubject:@"yo!"];
    [mailCont setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"surendherbtech@gmail.com"]];
    [mailCont setMessageBody:@"Don't ever want to give you up" isHTML:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:mailCont animated:YES];
    [mailCont release];
}


}


- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

It display good but what i need now is, i want the mail to be sent without the knowledge of user when he taps the button. It must send without user clicking send option.

Can anyone please tell me how to send mail automatically
Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to connect to a SMTP server and talk to it

Comment: @phix23 Can you tell me the procedure of how to connect to server

Answer (score 5):

Luckily, this isn't possible with `MFMailComposeViewController`. I sure wouldn't want some app to send email on my behalf without knowing.

You could either talk directly with your own mail server via SMTP (which is fairly difficult to do in Cocoa and you'd also have to include your credentials in the app, which is a security risk), or use regular HTTP to instruct some web service (perhaps a script on your server) to send the email for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [libetpan](https://github.com/dinhviethoa/libetpan/), with which I had success porting to iOS.

Comment: Can Apple reject it when submit to Store?

Comment: @ZuzooVn They can reject anything at any time.

Comment: Can you upload the app which automatically send email to Appstore?